# Should the word دَسَّاهَا have a ي in it in سورة الشمس ayat number 10?

Tags: arabic, qiraat

I have encountered two different ways of spelling the word دَسَّاهَا as it appears on سورة الشمس. One of them doesn't use the letter ي in it and other one does. For example, quran.com doesn't use the letter ي.

[image]

On the other hand, my copy of mushaf, use the letter ي in the word دَسَّاهَا.

[image]

I can find similiar usage in different words. For example, the word  سَوَّاهَا in ayah 7 is spelling in my mushaf like this;

[image]

Moreover, I find this kind of usage in another book (not a mushaf) that I have. Notice that both this book and my mushaf is printed by Turkish publishers.

My questions is, **Why is there such difference in spelling** and **Does similiar usage appear in books that are not published in Turkey**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [7 ways to recite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qira%27at#The_Ten_Readers_and_Their_Transmitters) the Quran. In the image you showed, it is witten like this because it describes Al-Kisa'ai method of recitation.

If you go to Surah [As-Shams](http://quran.com/91) you will see that it is written likes this:

[image]

**However, If you want to write it in the Arabic language, it should be written like this**:

[image]

### So why is the word written in the Quran different from the one in Arabic ?

Scholars, to make it easy for us, decided to write it this way to give us a hint that this specific word could be read/recited in another way(another Qira'at). An example is found in the image you have put in your question. Thus, they added a "ya'a" with no dots and replaced the long "Alef" with really small letter above the "Ya'a" to make it easier for reciters tell which is which.

Here is a [recitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkY95FYCFkA) By Hafs(common everywhere) and [another recitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLd1co_GUKo) of the same verse by Kisa'i

There is a book that explains why these unknown ways of writing the arabic words in the Quran is different. I will update the answer as soon as I remember the name.