# Had the Uthmanic codices differences in them?

Tags: quran, history, uloom-al-quran, mushaf

Salamun aleikum,

I have a question, regarding the compilation of the Quran.
My question is about the differences in the Uthmanic codices, which were sent to different cities to unite the Ummah on this topic. So, I read two statements on this topic:

1. In Al-Azamis book „The History of the Quranic Text“, he quotes on page 99 (from Abu Ubaid, Fada‘il and ad-Dani, al-Muqni), that there are variations of no more than 40 characters throughout the 6 mushafs, concerning only one letter, with an exception of the exclusion of a „he“ in one verse.
2. Somewhere else, where I am going to post the link, there is given another source, where it states that in verse 9:100 the word „min“ is only there in the Makkan Mushaf. So there would be another word, which is either included or excluded.
   https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/259588/facts-about-the-writing-of-the-mus-haf

So my question, are these two complementary or one of them wrong or did I understood something comepletely wrong?

So ist would be great, if someone clarifies this point, because this topic really confused me.
May Allah protect Us from going to a wrong path and protect our heart from the whisper of the Shaitan.

Comment: You should avoid asking multiple questions in the same post. If you have two questions, ask two separate questions.

Comment: I’m new here, so thank you for this clarification.

Comment: No problem. You can edit your post to limit it to one question

Comment: Now it’s one question.

Comment: This is a question on rasm al-Mushaf not qira'at. You'd better use the tag uloom-al-quran. See also [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30409/how-to-explain-the-recitation-لَئِنْ-انجــينا-verse-6-63-by-al-azami-in-his-bo) related question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Masahif of Uthman (RA) did have differences between them. Those differences were limited to the addition or subtraction of one or two letters. I haven't found differences of more than that.

The difference you mention of 9:100 is a difference in the addition or subtraction of "من" which is only two letters. The Mushaf of Makkah had a من while the others did not.

I cannot exactly comment on what Al-Azami's book is saying since I don't have access to it. But, even ad-Dani in al-Muqni mentions the difference in 9:100 between the Masahif. Perhaps you misunderstood the book.

Comment: I think I misunderstood his wording, but thanks for the response.